# Play framework + GWT + Restful

Tags: rest, gwt, playframework

We're developing an app using play framework for the backend (with Restful services), and GWT in the client . We want to call Restful services from GWT. Can we use RestyGWT just to build the request and get JSON?

I have read the RestyGWT documentation (http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html) but I don't have all clear, because we don't need build Restful service, just call them from client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should rather try something and post a relevant issue with the approaches you tried instead to get useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case you can use two feature of `RestyGWT`:

1. Calling Restful web services which developed using `Play Framework`, see [this](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html#REST_Services) part of documentations.
2. Manipulating JSON objects in your GWT application using RestyGWT API for encoding and decoding Java Object to JSON, see [this](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html#JSON_Encoder_Decoders) part of documentations.

Comment: But what is the difference between build a request with parameters, type of the request(GET, POST), process the response, and do it using RestyGWT?

Comment: Your question is very general, please specify your particular problem and try to read documentation precisely.